# What's the difference between partx and kpartx?

Tags: linux

I read the man pages on both, and they seems to be interchangeable and to be doing the same job.

So can someone explain when I should use partx, and when kpartx ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

partx asks the kernel to probe a given device and re-read the partition table.  The kernel is doing the work here.

kpartx creates device mapper entries and so can be used by devices that the kernel does not natively support partitioning, such as multipath device mapper devices ("kpartx" is part of multipath-tools) or files.

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/archives/dm-devel/2014-September/msg00077.html backs this up..

Comment: The next question of course, is why are they called like this: intuitively, I'd expect the `kpartx` to be the one relying on the **k**ernel to do the work, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are pretty much the same, but kpartx only deals with disk images while partx also allows you to map partitions within a block device.

Comment: Notice that the kernel _does_ support partitions on loop devices without necessarily using `kpartx` / device-mapper. Either `losetup -P` or `partx -a /dev/loop0` are able to give you access to partitions on a loop device (disk image).